# URL variable coming through as `"function String() { [native code] }"`

Tags: c#, typescript, routes, string-parsing

I have a typescript method `saveNewCase()` that calls `Save()` in the C# controller using a route:

```
export function saveNewCase(caseName: string) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        $.post('/case/save/new/' + caseName)
            .then(() => resolve())
            .catch(e => reject(e));
    });
}
```

The controller then creates a new object using the `caseName`:

```
[HttpPost("case/save/new/{name}")]
public async Task<IActionResult> Save([FromRoute] string name)
{
    //uses variable 'name'
}
```

But when I debug I can see that `name` is coming through as `"function String() { [native code] }"` instead of the string it's been sent as. All the other questions I've found on this are about mishandling of functions, but this is a simple string variable.

I do the same thing with another method, only difference is that the variable is an int, and it works fine.

What's going on here, and how can I fix it?

Comment: The problem is probably in the code which calls `saveNewCase`, which seems to be passing the wrong string. Can you edit the question to include the code where `saveNewCase` is called?

Comment: @kaya3 Thanks, the problem was exactly that, I updated the code and it works now

Comment: Alright, glad I was able to help.